# Mysql Input/Output query

Tags: mysql

I have two querys:

```
  SELECT LancamentoEntrada.*,
         TipoEntrada.descricao AS nome,
         Usuario.nome AS obreiro
    FROM lancamento_entradas LancamentoEntrada,
         tipo_entradas TipoEntrada,
         obreiros Obreiro,
         usuarios Usuario
   WHERE LancamentoEntrada.tipo_entrada_id = TipoEntrada.id
     AND TipoEntrada.somar_caixa = 1
     AND LancamentoEntrada.obreiro_id = Obreiro.id
     AND Usuario.id = Obreiro.usuario_id
     AND LancamentoEntrada.data_entrada >= '{$begin}'
     AND LancamentoEntrada.data_entrada <= '{$end}'
ORDER BY LancamentoEntrada.data_entrada
```

And

```
  SELECT LancamentoSaida.*,
         TipoSaida.descricao AS nome
    FROM lancamento_saidas LancamentoSaida,
         tipo_saidas TipoSaida
   WHERE LancamentoSaida.tipo_saida_id = TipoSaida.id
     AND TipoSaida.somar_caixa = 1
     AND LancamentoSaida.data_saida >= '{$begin}'
     AND LancamentoSaida.data_saida <= '{$end}'
ORDER BY LancamentoSaida.data_saida
```

Which generate the follow arrays:

```
// Query 1
Array(
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 3
        [tipo_entrada_id] => 1
        [data_entrada] => 2012-05-08
        [data_vencimento] => 2012-05-08
        [obreiro_id] => 2
        [valor_pago] => 20.00
        [valor_pagar] => 0.01
        [observacoes] => TESTE
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [...]
    )
)

// Query 2
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 1
        [tipo_saida_id] => 1
        [data_saida] => 2012-05-08
        [data_vencimento] => 2012-05-08
        [valor_pago] => 200.00
        [observacoes] => tESTE
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [...]
    )
)
```

But, I want to do one query, listing inputs and outputs, how I can acomplish this?
If need more explanation, please, ask-me.

**EDIT 1**

inputs are generated from first query, output from second.

**EDIT 2**

The querys need to generate report of financial input/output, so, the first query get all input stored and the second get all output generated, both betwenn from one period. I need to generate a list with all, input and output, ordered by date.

```
Edit 3
```

I have done this query, the problem is, how I know when is input and when is output?

Tried `ISNULL` and `CASEs`, but not work.

```
(SELECT LancamentoEntrada.data_entrada AS data,
    LancamentoEntrada.data_vencimento AS vencimento,
    LancamentoEntrada.valor_pago AS valor,
    LancamentoEntrada.observacoes AS observacoes,
    TipoEntrada.descricao AS nome
   FROM lancamento_entradas LancamentoEntrada,
    tipo_entradas TipoEntrada
  WHERE LancamentoEntrada.tipo_entrada_id = TipoEntrada.id
    AND TipoEntrada.somar_caixa = 1
)

UNION

(SELECT LancamentoSaida.data_saida AS data,
    LancamentoSaida.data_vencimento AS vencimento,
    LancamentoSaida.valor_pago AS valor,
    LancamentoSaida.observacoes AS observacoes,
    TipoSaida.descricao AS nome
   FROM lancamento_saidas LancamentoSaida,
    tipo_saidas TipoSaida
  WHERE LancamentoSaida.tipo_saida_id = TipoSaida.id
    AND TipoSaida.somar_caixa = 1
)
```

Comment: have u tried union ?  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

Comment: When you say *"listing inputs and outputs"*, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Blending the result of the first query to the second using the structure of the first.

Comment: So are the values of data_entrada  and data_entrada  from the first query become the values you use fro Begin and end on the second query?

Comment: @sree no, I have not. I will read.

Comment: @ConradFrix sorry, I did not understand your last comment.

Comment: @GabrielSantos Ok can you clarify what you mean by *"inputs are generated from first query, output from second."*

Comment: I don't think `union` will do any good here.. these queries have different resultsets.. it's not really that hard to write a single query that does it. You need to identify a FK field or a set of fields which is/are common for these two tables and use `join` in your query

Comment: @ConradFrix the querys need to generate report of financial input/output, so, the first query get all input stored and the second generate all output generated, both betwenn one period. I need to generate a list with all, input and output, ordered by date.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe i think you might have mistaken his question... :)

Comment: @sree Can you enlighten me? I think I really didn't understand

Comment: See updated question, with UNION, which I thin will do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing you still need is to identify which records came from which query you just need to add a literal to each query.

```
( SELECT 
      'Input' as rec_type,

     LancamentoEntrada.data_entrada AS data,
    LancamentoEntrada.data_vencimento AS vencimento,
    LancamentoEntrada.valor_pago AS valor,
    LancamentoEntrada.observacoes AS observacoes,
    TipoEntrada.descricao AS nome
   FROM lancamento_entradas LancamentoEntrada,
    tipo_entradas TipoEntrada
  WHERE LancamentoEntrada.tipo_entrada_id = TipoEntrada.id
    AND TipoEntrada.somar_caixa = 1
)

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
      'Output' as rec_type,

      LancamentoSaida.data_saida AS data,
    LancamentoSaida.data_vencimento AS vencimento,
    LancamentoSaida.valor_pago AS valor,
    LancamentoSaida.observacoes AS observacoes,
    TipoSaida.descricao AS nome
   FROM lancamento_saidas LancamentoSaida,
    tipo_saidas TipoSaida
  WHERE LancamentoSaida.tipo_saida_id = TipoSaida.id
    AND TipoSaida.somar_caixa = 1
)
```

As an aside you'll get better performance if you `UNION ALL` Since `UNION` would remove duplicates from the two sets which you won't have in this case.